# SQLite3 do not always work properly (cannot prepare or execute queries)

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am using an MacMini for development in swift and I am testing on an iPhone 6S.

I tried to install Sqlite-wrappers (SQLite.swift, fmdb) but they both crashed my app on startup. So I use the pure sqlite3-API.

At first I created a pointer to the DB and made it available as a static variable.

```
static var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
.....
sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db)
```

But I got sometimes a Bad_Access crash. Searched the net. Found "do not use 1 pointer in different threads".

So now I create a pointer at the moment I need it in the different threads with open-statement, do always a sqlite3_reset, a finalize and then I close it.

```
static func getDBPointer() -> OpaquePointer? {
    var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
    if sqlite3_open(dbFile, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error opening database")
    } else {
        print("******************* DB opened")
    }
    return db
}
```

Worked fine for a few days, no problems, no Bad_Access.

But now all the DB behaves very strange.
It worked fine for a minute and then I cant insert or update rows and the next statement works fine again.
"delete * from table" is no problem most of the time, but now and then it fails. All sqlite3_prepare_v2()-Statements worked fine and I can see no syntax problem.
On the next try (same statements, all wellformed with proper data) I get nearly always "Failed to prepare ..."

Here a short example of code:

```
let db = getDBPointer()

let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO vorstellung_info (vorstellung_nr,datum,vorstellung,haus,autor) VALUES (\(vorst_num),\(vorst_datum),'\(vorstellung_name)','\(vorst_haus)','\(vorst_autor)');"

print("Insert vorstellung string: \(insertStatementString)")

var insertStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil

if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
        print("Done well.")
    } else {
        print("Could not insert row in vorstellung_info: \(insertStatementString)")
    }
} else {
    print("INSERT statement to vorstellung_info could not be prepared.")
}
sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
sqlite3_close_v2(db)
```

Output:

```
Insert vorstellung string: INSERT INTO vorstellung_info (vorstellung_nr,datum,vorstellung,haus,autor) VALUES (45127,1481382000000,'TEST-WantToSee','Thats the place','Interesting author');
Could not insert row in vorstellung_info: INSERT INTO vorstellung_info (vorstellung_nr,datum,vorstellung,haus,autor) VALUES (45127,1481382000000,'TEST-WantToSee','Thats the place','Interesting author');
```

And as I said before: sometimes even the prepare statement fails.

The create table statement for this example:

```
let createVorstellungInfo = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vorstellung_info(" +
            "vorstellung_nr INT," +
            "datum INT," +
            "vorstellung TEXT," +
            "haus TEXT," +
        "autor TEXT);"
```

The program has a lot of "conversation" with a server via session, so most of the non-select-statements are asynch in a session.task or static func that are called by such task.

Edit:

added "String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))" to any possible location

"cannot prepare":

```
SELECT statement could not be prepared: SELECT * from rechnung_vorst where rechnung_nr = 9868681 AND vorstellung_nr = 45138;
------------------------- 
database is locked
```

"Cant load"

```
Veranstalter could not get loaded: SELECT veranstalter_nname, veranstalter_vname, veranstalter_uid, veranstalter_ort, veranstalter_plz, veranstalter_str FROM veranstalter WHERE veranstalter_nr = 2062491;
------------------------- 
unknown error
```

These are only 2 examples of dozends of messages.
By the way: took me 4 - 5 attempts to get these messages (all within one attempt). First it worked fine, then these errors and then it worked again ...

Comment: [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threaded SQLite is hard. It is very interesting, and I will never say that you should not try to address this challenge yourself. But if you want to spend your time elsewhere, I suggest you have a look at [GRDB.swift](http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift). It provides more concurrency guarantees than other libraries: http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift#concurrency